# Как в cmd.exe сменить директорию по ярлыку?

Tags: windows, cmd

`cd Документы.lnk`
  выдает ошибку "Неверно задано имя папки", а

`Документы.lnk`

открывает папку в explorer.exe. Мне нужно именно перейти по ярлыку в терминале, как это сделать?

Comment: для этого символические ссылки предназначены а не ярлыки `mklink /D документы "C:\документы"`

Comment: а так `lnk`-ярлык это бинарый файл, с описание структуры можете ознакомится тут -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305.aspx

Comment: Т.е. у меня нет такой возможности?

Comment: думаю, что нет. Замените на символическую ссылку-то, можете ее даже назвать `документы.lnk`, если хотите :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я дико НЕ понимаю зачем это вообще может быть нужно.

Но решение существует:

https://superuser.com/questions/806932/how-can-i-parse-a-lnk-shortcut-from-the-command-prompt-in-windows

Вот код батника, для перехода в каталог, из пропарсенного  lnk-файла (путь к которому поступает в виде параметра):

```
@echo off
echo set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")>Tmp.vbs
echo set Lnk = WshShell.Createshortcut(WScript.Arguments(0))>>Tmp.vbs
echo WScript.Echo Lnk.TargetPath>>Tmp.vbs
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('cscript //nologo Tmp.vbs "%~1"') do del Tmp.vbs & cd /d "%%d"
```

Comment: Дополню. Переход в каталог командой **CD** будет успешным, если каталог находится на **ТЕКУЩЕМ** диске.

Comment: Жаль, что нет родного решения. Спасибо